# Python find index in a string

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I am trying to print the index of the word in this string below. The problem right now is that it is checking for each element in the list and returning false. How can I make it return "False" if the word isn't in the list and not check it each element?

```
target = "dont"
string = "we dont need no education we dont need to thought control no we dont"
liste = string.split() 
for index, item in enumerate(liste):
        if target in item:
                print index, item
        else:
                print 'False'
```

Output:

```
False
1 dont
False
False
False
False
6 dont
False
False
False
False
False
False
13 dont
```

Comment: @I know python I thought you wanted to  `return "False"`? You realise printing is not returning and `False` is a boolean in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if the word is in the list first:

```
 if word not in liste:
```

So if you want to return put it in a function:

```
def f(t, s):
    liste = s.split()
    if t not in liste:
        return False
    for index, item in enumerate(liste):
        if t == item:
            print index, item
    return True
```

Unless you want to match substrings it should  also be `if t == item:`, If you want to return all the indexes you can return a list comp:

```
def f(t, s):
    liste = s.split()
    if t not in liste:
        return False
    return [index for index, item in enumerate(liste) if t == item]
```

Comment: How can I make the output be: dont [1, 6, 13] in a list

Comment: @Iknowpython, the second code returns `[1, 6, 13]`, if you want the word also just return it with the list  , `return t, [index for index, item in enumerate(liste) if t == item] -> ('dont', [1, 6, 13])` or use a dict

Comment: I only getting: 
[1, 6, 13] not 'dont' in front of it.

Comment: then you have not added the code above because as posted it produces `('dont', [1, 6, 13])` which is a tuple containing the target string and the list of indexes

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
target = "dont"
string = "we dont need no education we dont need to thought control no we dont"
liste = string.split()
if target in liste:
    for index, item in enumerate(liste):
        if target == item:
            print index, item
else:
    print 'False'
```

Comment: `if target in item`  will match substrings, if you considered substrings a match there would be no point splitting before using in to check in the first place.